# How to calculate sum of double values in firebase and ignore null values, android studio?

Tags: android, firebase

I am able to calculate the sum provided all keys has child "totalpetrol", if this child is not existing in any key, my app crashes. So how can I ignore null values and calculate the sum of values that are existing.

my code:

```
mDatabase.orderByChild("totalpetrol").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists() && snapshot.getChildren().iterator().hasNext()){
                    Double sum_petrol = Double.valueOf(0);
                    Double sum_diesel = Double.valueOf(0);
                    for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>)ds.getValue();
                        //calculate total petrol litres
                        assert map != null;
                        Object sales_petrol = map.get("totalpetrol");
                        Double pValue = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(sales_petrol));
                        sum_petrol += pValue;
                        Log.d("totalpetrol", String.valueOf(sum_petrol));
                        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mashava_petrol);
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(sum_petrol));


                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Error: ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Error: "+error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I have tried wraping by this statement to check if the child exists in all keys:

```
if (snapshot.child("totalpetrol").exists() && snapshot.child("totaldiesel").exists())
```

When I do this once it detects that there is a key which does not have a child, it jumps to the else statement when I have a simple toast message.

So the code work if the child exists in all keys, removing it from one key everything goes wrong, but i want it to calculate sum of all existing values.

database structure is similar to this, https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F59434376%2Fwhy-the-entries-are-looped-continuously-in-firebase-database&psig=AOvVaw3a1lLUkNhsBWmKzdb73lSn&ust=1620024210983000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKCL0NGyqvACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAO So please consider a child called "totalpetrol" is there, and is only missing in one of keys.

how can i solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on your code, you have introduced orderByChild("totalpetrol")

Thats fine, so I assume (since firebase does not store empty child nodes) a key node which has totalpetrol == null , will not exist in the database at all, so if you say orderByChild("totalpetrol") I think key nodes that have null values will show at the end/bottom/last (if not first). So correct your line code to this:
mDatabase.orderByChild("totalpetrol").startAfter(null).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()

I have just added .startAfter(null)
It should work, or maybe you need startBefore(null)